# Unable to send email in laravel in server

Tags: php, laravel, email, cpanel

I've following configuration in environment file,

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD='mypassword'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I've made user registration from `RegistrationController` and send email to verify that user. It works perfectly in the local LAMP server with ubantu. But, following error is encountered in C Panel.

> Swift_TransportException  Connection could not be established with
>   host smtp.gmail.com [Network is unreachable #101]

Here is the register function in controller,

```
protected function register(Request $request)
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name'     => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email'    => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);

    try {
        $validatedData['password']      = bcrypt(array_get($validatedData, 'password'));
        $validatedData['activate_code'] = str_random(30).time();
        if($request->has('company') && $request->company=='on')
        {
            $validatedData['role_id']   = 4;
        }
        else
        {
            $validatedData['role_id']   = 5;
        }
        $user                           = app(User::class)->create($validatedData);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        logger()->error($exception);
        return redirect()->back()->with('alert-danger', 'Unable to create new user.');
    }

    $user->notify(new UserRegisteredSuccessfully($user));
    return redirect()->back()->with('alert-success', 'Successfully created a new account. Please check your email and activate your account.');
}
```

I've already seen such issues and many question but none works in my case. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Please change port `465` to `587`

Comment: and mail_encryption=tls also

Comment: did you give a permission your gmail account to mail in other apps??

Comment: @AkbarMirsidikov no

Answer (score 1):

Update your `.env` file like:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD='mypassword'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: let me check once

Comment: I've got this error now, `stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`gains.nanosupercloud.com' did not match expected CN=`smtp.gmail.com'`

Answer (score 1):

firstable, once you have created gmail account for mailing from your website, You must give a permission your gmail account for mailing from other app.
to do this...

1) go to your gmail account and click on "`settings -> FORWARDING and POP/IMAP`" link. And follow these instructions like below picture...

[image]

2)  go to this link `https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?utm_source=google-account&utm_medium=web`
and enable this like below picture...

[image]

3) make sure thst if your web app is working on http protocol use `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`  and `MAIL_PORT=587` otherwise `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl` and `MAIL_PORT=465`

Comment: Please add images in english language it would be easy to understand

Comment: CHANGED FOR YOU

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: are your login and pass true??

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some changes with your .env config and with your account

1) Change mail port to 587 and encryption

```
 MAIL_PORT=587
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

2) Enable IMAP in your email account to use that protocol

3) Enable access for the app to your account

Answer (score 0):

change `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` to `MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail`

After completion of *`.env`* edit, enter this command in your terminal for clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`