# proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons problem in laravel mail sending in server

Tags: php, laravel, email, cpanel

I have hosted a laravel project in cpanel(shared hosting) and I've got issue while sending emails with laravel mail function.

My Previous question : [Unable to send email in laravel in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53869248/unable-to-send-email-in-laravel-in-server)

Now, I don't have swift mailer problem but I've got new issue

> proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons

I've tried normal mail sending in server with following code,

```
<?php
$to      = 'sagautam5@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

It works correctly and sends email but when I try following code in laravel

```
Route::get('testEmail', function ()
{

    $data = [
        'key'     => 'value'
    ];

    Mail::send([], [], function ($message) {
        $message->from('another@email.com', 'My name');
        $message->subject('subject');
        $message->to('sagautam5@gmail.com');
    });

    dd(Mail::failures());
});
```

proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons issue is encountered.

[image]

I'm not too much familiar with the production server. Any help is appreciated. I'm stuck here from 2 days

Comment: are you able to modify `php.ini` settings on your hosting?

Comment: I don't have that access in my hosting

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854659/unable-to-send-emails-in-laravel-using-swift-mailer-proc-open-function-disab out. You might be able to get around this by using a different mail client

Comment: or just change hosting

Comment: @apokryfos I've look at the question in the link you have provided. but not get the idea

Comment: setting `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` should not require calling `proc_open` at all. You are currently using `sendmail` which does require calling `proc_open`

Comment: with smtp connection couldn't established error is encountered

Comment: @apokryfos Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Network is unreachable #101] this error

Comment: gmail might be blocking your hosting server. Try using a different smtp server

Comment: I think you need to disable it in `disable_functions` in `php.ini` and then try again.

Comment: I don't have that access

Comment: Someone had a similar issue with shared hosting and there is a potential resolution on this link. Hopefully it may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401630/proc-open-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons-php-error

Answer (score 0):

First time you need to run this command:

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=flare-config`

***for next time you should open this file below path of your project***
`config/flare.php`
then find `collect_git_information` and change value to `FALSE`
finaly you should run below commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan route:clear

php artisan view:clear

php artisan config:cache
```